# Where does the PHP/MySQL connection take its default charset?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I use `mysql_connect` to a database solely defined in UTF-8. Everywhere I can look in the configuration, I see `UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)` or `utf8_general_ci`.

However, when I open the PHP connection, then use `echo mysql_client_encoding();`, I get `latin1` as an output, which is pretty unexpected. Is it taken from some kind of PHP/Apache configuration?

Comment: Belongs to ServerFault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In /etc/mysql/my.cnf add this line under [client]

```
default-character-set=utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the encoding for your PHP MySQL connection as it does not read it from your table/database definition. Do it like this:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
// or in OOP style:
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```